# C# SAP Soap error: The value 07:41:39.4780076+03:00 is not a valid time. It does not correspond to the XML format for ABAP

Tags: c#, .net, soap, abap

There is an error when I am trying to add current time to Time field in SAP using method

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime();
```

Then I get the error message:

> The value `07:41:39.4780076+03:00` is not a valid time. It does not
>   correspond to the XML format for ABAP.

This works with Datetime fields but not in Time fields

```
DateTime.UtcNow;
```

I have tried to search but there are no good examples.

EDIT:

This is same as my problem

[WSDL time format is ignored from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281593/wsdl-time-format-is-ignored-from-visual-studio)

These questions are quite close but is there a way doing this without big changes in automatically generated code from WDSL

[Serializing a DataType="time" field using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402379/serializing-a-datatype-time-field-using-xmlserializer)

[Serializing DateTime to time without milliseconds and gmt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101533/serializing-datetime-to-time-without-milliseconds-and-gmt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It is based on links above an mainly this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402568/4845680

I needed to make new partial class which implements new method which generates the datetime and the XML element. The old method is set to [XmlIgnore] and the new method generates XML element.

Generated Reference.cs

```
namespace MyService.SAPNamespace {

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://sap.com/....")]
public partial class SAPClassRequestBundle : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged{

    private System.DateTime zTimeField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] //This line is added so that its not used
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://sap.com/....", DataType="time", Order=106)]
    public System.DateTime ZTime {
        get {
            return this.zTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.zTimeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ZTime");
        }
    }

}
```

}

My new class SapWsdlFix.cs which implements new method ZTimeString

```
namespace MyService.SAPNamespace {
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://sap.com/....")]
public partial class SAPClassRequestBundle : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "ZTime", Namespace = "http://sap.com/....", DataType = "string", Order = 106)]
    public System.String ZTimeString {
        get
        {
            return this.zTimeField.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }
        set
        {
            this.zTimeField = System.DateTime.ParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ZTime");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Differences in short for the custom class.

- ElementName-attribute is set to same as the original Reference.cs method name
- DataType-attribute is changed to String from Time

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "ZTime", Namespace = "http://sap.com/....", DataType = "string", Order = 106)]

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution how to do that without editing generated code.

```
public partial class SAPClassRequestBundle : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "ZTime", Namespace = "http://sap.com/....", DataType = "string", Order = 107)]
public System.String ZTimeString 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.zTimeField.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }
        set
        {
            this.zTimeField = System.DateTime.ParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ZTime");
        }
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeZTime()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically to get it working just assign Order param to non taken value and add method with name matching pattern ShouldSerialize{FieldName} and returning false.

Solution was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090247/1104587

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error from a SAP ByD SOAP API. There is a big difference between `DateTime` and `Time`.

If the datatype is `Time` then the value should follow this format `hh:mm:ss`, for example `13:15:30`.

If it's DateTime then it should have this format: `yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ`. For example `2021-09-27T12:30:00Z`.